# Remove default order by from union Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I want to display data like this:

```
Column1        Column2
-----------------------
TotalAvg         60%

A1               50%

B1               70%

Z1               60%
```

My sql script is something like:

```
select 'Total Avg' as Column1,'60%' as Column2

union

select Column1,Column2 from tblAvg
```

and result I am getting is something like this:

```
Column1        Column2
------------------------

A1               50%

B1               70%

TotalAvg         60%

Z1               60%
```

Question: I want to remove default ordering and want result in the order we are doing union tables.

Comment: There isn't a "default" order. You're receiving rows in whatever manner the database engine finds most efficient to produce. If you want a particular ordering, you have to find a way to express that in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  select 0 as pos, 'Total Avg' as Column1, '60%' as Column2
  union
  select 1 as pos,                Column1,          Column2 from tblAvg 
)
  AS data
ORDER BY
  pos, column1, column2
```

Comment: No need for the subquery, an `order by` affects the entire union

Comment: @Andomar - In my mind it makes it clearer to use a sub-query.  It just makes it less ambiguous to my tired old eyes :)

Comment: @bridge - Sorry dude, please don't change my layout, especially without asking *(as the edit didn't change anything factual, just layout)*. I laid it out as I did for specific reasons. Thanks for the suggestion though, but I'm going to roll it back.

Comment: @Dems Sorry - there I was thinking you'd just pasted in a hurry!

Comment: Agreed, explicit subquery is less ambiguous!  Just as a note, the second `as pos` can be omitted as the database will ignore it

Comment: Must admit I went straight to subquery as well, have a vague memory of an attempt at something more complex failing,may have been due to wanting to order each part of the union, and I agree it makes the intent of the query  much clearer.

Answer (score 9):

You could add a column that specifies the result order:

```
select 'Total Avg' as Column1,'60%' as Column2, 1 as OrderCol
union
select Column1,Column2, 2 from tblAvg
order by OrderCol
```

Without an `order by`, the database is free to return rows in any order.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
select * From
(
select 'Total Avg' as Column1,'60%' as Column2, 1 as ItemOrder

union

select Column1,Column2,2 from tblAvg
) innertable
Order By ItemOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
select 'Total Avg' as Column1,'60%' as Column2

union all

select Column1,Column2 from tblAvg
```

Comment: The *only* way to guarantee the order of rows in a result set is to use `ORDER BY` - anything else is just based on coincidence, and may break at any time.

Comment: Union ALL does not sort the data, but does not remove duplicates.

Comment: @ParadoX - as you say, `UNION ALL` does not sort the data - but the OP wants the data sorted - "want result in the order we are doing union tables"

Comment: Yes, I know order by is the best way. But, 'union all' "remove default ordering".

Comment: Before submitting your answer. Always look for the already posted ones. And then post if you think your method is best or efficient or short or easiest. Otherwise it may cause even down-votes

Comment: Of Course, you have absolutely right! But, He wants to remove default ordering. UNION ALL removes it.

Comment: @ParadoX - neither `UNION` nor `UNION ALL` have *any* defined behaviour when it comes to ordering. To say that `UNION ALL` "removes" ordering is incorrect, because `UNION` doesn't *apply* ordering.